# XBMC 13.2 linker error on Raspberry Pi: undefined references to COMXImage and g_OMXImage

Tags: compilation, compiler-errors, raspberry-pi, raspbian, xbmc

I have tried to compile XBMC 13.2 Gotham on my Raspberry Pi using DistCC to speed up compilation. When it comes to linking, I got the following error:

```
AR      xbmc/cores/paplayer/paplayer.a
LD      xbmc.bin
xbmc/linux/linux.a(RBP.o): In function `CRBP::Initialize()':
RBP.cpp:(.text+0x468): undefined reference to `COMXImage::Initialize()'
RBP.cpp:(.text+0x4d0): undefined reference to `g_OMXImage'
xbmc/linux/linux.a(RBP.o): In function `CRBP::Deinitialize()':
RBP.cpp:(.text+0x7cc): undefined reference to `COMXImage::Deinitialize()'
RBP.cpp:(.text+0x878): undefined reference to `g_OMXImage'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
distcc[24757] ERROR: compile (null) on localhost failed
distcc[24756] ERROR: compile (null) on localhost failed
Makefile:541: recipe for target 'xbmc.bin' failed
make: *** [xbmc.bin] Error 1
```

The COMXImage class is present in the source code of `xbmc/cores/omxplayer`.

For compile preparation I used the commands from [RaspbianXBMC](http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianXBMC).

The source code has been checked out from the [XBMC Github Repository](https://github.com/xbmc/xbmc) using tag **13.2**.

I have run `./boostrap` and `./configure` with the following options:

```
./configure --build=arm-linux-gnueabihf --with-platform=raspberry-pi \
--disable-gl --enable-gles --disable-x11 --disable-sdl --enable-ccache \
--enable-optimizations --enable-external-libraries --disable-goom \ 
--disable-hal --disable-pulse --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau \ 
--disable-xrandr --disable-airplay --disable-alsa --enable-avahi \
--enable-libbluray --enable-dvdcss --disable-debug --disable-joystick \
--enable-mid --enable-nfs --disable-profiling --disable-projectm \
--enable-rsxs --enable-rtmp --enable-optical-drive --enable-libcec
```

Before complete compilation i fetched and successfully built TAGLIB and libcec from their own git repositories using the latest version.

I could provide the output of `./configure` if this might help.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

open RBP.cpp file
and remove lines containing

`g_OMXImage.Initialize()`

and

`if (m_omx_image_init)
   g_OMXImage.Deinitialize();`

and then try to re-compile